# IE Not Picking up Blur Event (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I did a quick search, but couldn't find a specific solution to this (I'm sure it HAS been answered) but, I need to figure this out...

Anyone know why this won't work in IE?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).blur(function() {
        window.close();
    });
});
```

And what to do instead?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you can't detect a click outside the window itself, which seems to be what you're trying to do.

I would recommend a [dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead of a new window if you want it to close. They have nifty features like loading in whole other pages, and even iframes.

Comment: I'm down with this solution... I've been using Facebox.  The only problem I have is I need a javascript function to fire the dialogue box and facebox looks for an href... I'm a little tired of looking up dialogue boxes at the moment... gahhhhh

Comment: Well, I ended up going with your idea... a dialogue box.  I can't say you really answered the question, but it worked so I'll give you the check mark.

Comment: well, you can't really capture the `blur` event of the `body` because it's not an input, which is mostly what `blur` is for. blur = when it loses focus. and since 'body' or 'document' can't have focus (a cursor in it) it can't logically have a blur. it seemed like you were trying to capture when you click outside the window, which is more like a dialog box behavior.

Answer (score 1):

try binding the blur to `body` instead of `document`

Comment: this worked.  I gave the body an ID tag and bound it.  I had to keep the $(document) too for all the other browsers that actually work.

Comment: I take it back.  It didn't work.  Anytime you click anything, the window closes.

Comment: try adding `$('body').click(function() { return false; });`

Comment: I ended up using contagious's solution, but I gave you an up vote for being helpful and very close to the answer.